# Is there a way to change the keyboard shortcut to terminate a process(crtl + c) in iterm2

Tags: iterm2

My control is not working so is there a way to change the keyboard shortcut in iterm2. I tried to look for it in the preferences but i did not find any method.

Answer (score -1):

To change the keyboard shortcut in Linux:

1. Go to **System Settings**.
2. Go to **Keyboard**.
3. Select **Shortcut Tab**.
4. From the left Pan Select **Launchers**.
5. From Keyboard shortcuts select **Launch Terminal**.
6. From Keyboard bindings click on **unassigned**.
7. Press the keys which you want to set.

That's all.

For your MAC Terminal go to this https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-keys.html page